# Devise token_authenticatable without session cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, session-cookies, access-token

I'm using Rails 3 and I've succesfully built a web api. For a bunch of controllers login is required so i decided to use Devise and token_authenticable. It IS working but not quite as I was expecting: I though I needed to supply my login token for each request instead it looks like it's only needed once and then the system creates a cookie in the response just like a normal browser session. I want achieve something like facebook graph api where each request needs to have submitted the session token in order to work.

Is there any flag that I can set to instruct Devise to not send session cookies if I'm using web api and send session cookies if I'm using the browser?

Comment: If it sends a session cookie and you ignore it --- is there any harm done?

Comment: That's fine too. In fact that's how it's currently working. It's definitely not a matter of life or death... I'm just curious

Comment: If you store your session in a database (or memcache or whatever), each time you sign a user, you add a row in your base. So it might be a problem if you API is widely use. So it would be nise if you can sign in a user but not storing the session.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

There was a line in Sessions controller of my API:

```
 warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
```

It was logging user in and creating a session (which I didn't notice at first)

The solution is to use something similar to this (found in the [blogpost](http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/)):

```
@user=User.find_by_email(email.downcase)
if @user.nil?
  render :status=>401, :json=>{:message=>"Invalid email or password."}
  return
end

# http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/TokenAuthenticatable
@user.ensure_authentication_token!

if not @user.valid_password?(password)
  logger.info("User #{email} failed signin, password \"#{password}\" is invalid")
  render :status=>401, :json=>{:message=>"Invalid email or password."}
else
  render :status=>200, :json=>{:token=>@user.authentication_token}
end
```

Basically not logging user in, but retrieving the token. Other parts of application except for logging out were working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I used  `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` so that session is ignored.